# Proto deserialization from json will fail on new fields or unknown enum values

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

`proto` is designed so that introduction of new fields should not break your code that runs on older version.

But if you're using `json` conversion in `java` using `protobuf-java-util` then your old code will break on new fields or new enum values unknown to existing code...

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1610) on `github` but it does not get any attention. I hope to get some answers here.

Given message like this

```
message Msg {
    required string sender = 1;
    required string message = 2;
}
```

if we convert this to json and print using

```
JsonFormat.printer().print(msg)
```

we will have this result

```
{
  "sender": "me",
  "message": "message"
}
```

if we decode this json to `Msg` using its builder

```
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, builder)
```

we will get expected result... But if we try to decode similar `json` with additional `extra` field

```
{
  "sender": "me",
  "message": "message",
  "extra" : "some extra stuff"
}
```

we will fail with this exception

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field: extra in message proto.Msg
```

How is that nobody cares about this problem? So far my only solution to this is to write a parser from scratch that will ignore unknown fields and unknown enum values when parsing...

Is there something i overlooked or people simply dont use backwards compatibility features?

Comment: I've never used the json format so far, but I agree that it would make more sense for it to ignore unknown fields. That's how most other json-accepting programs behave also, and the way it works with binary protobufs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already fixed by google, the builder provides option to ignore unknown fields.

Comment: Can you please specify how can  this be done? I couldddn't find any documentationfor this

Comment: read the issue in the original question that i've created, when parsing string json to proto you create an instance like this JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, yourBuilder)

Comment: ignoringUnknownFields() was the fix